# iPhone IOS Bluetooth Name Fleet Vehicles Ford SYNC

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, synchronization

I have several new Ford vehicles with SYNC at a workplace and a driver could be assigned a different vehicle day to day.  It is easy enough to pair an iPhone to a single vehicle.  However, when pairing to a dozen or so vehicles I noticed a couple problems.   The most obvious is there are a fairly low number of devices that the head unit will accept to pair to.  I have to delete a pairing to be able to add another.  Not terrible and likely a manufacturer limitation.   The most annoying and time consuming problem is the Bluetooth name is the same for every vehicle.  The name is always “SYNC”.  There is no way I see to edit the name or add a note to the Bluetooth connection in IOS to signify a vehicle fleet number.  So the user has no idea which “SYNC” to connect to.   Much worse, when you can’t connect for some reason and need to blow away the old connection because it doesn’t appear as a new device to connect to, then you have to blow away every SYNC connection because you have no label signifying which connection belongs to which vehicle you’re using at the time.  Ford sells fleet vehicles and I’d think they would test such a scenario.  Any work around?  Any way to edit the SYNC name coming from the head unit to something like “SYNC 234” so that it contains a vehicle number?

Comment: You would need to ask Ford; the setting will be in their system

Comment: It seems that there are some limited changes you can make using dealer programming software https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbwdXjYUjqY but I don't think it would help you.  Can't you delete the phone from the vehicle side? It should show a meaningful name like "Dan's iPhone" so a driver could delete someone else's device if they are unable to pair.

Comment: Yes you can delete from the vehicle side.   However, in my experience it often doesn’t let you pair the device again until you also delete from the phone.  Deleting from the phone is the dubious operation because the names are all the same.